# 3.3V from 5V Voltage regulator

Tags: power-supply, voltage-regulator, 5v, 3.3v

I wish to build and get 3.3V from LM7805 voltage regulator with some extra parts like resistor and maybe a zener diode.

[image: Typical regulator circuit]

How can I achieve that, is it even possible to do that?

Comment: Yes, but whyyyyyyyyyyyy?

Comment: What level of power (or current) do you hope to get on the 3.3V side? Actually, you can plug in the numbers yourself at http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/electronic/zenereg.html

Comment: I wish to use that 7805 and to get 3.3V out approx 250-400mA

Comment: Just daisy-chain a [LM3940](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm3940.pdf) off of Vcc, add another 47uF and 0.1uF, and done.

Comment: @rdtsc: that regulator is not for noobs because of the precise capacitance and ESR needed to avoid oscillation; see http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/195122/lm2940-ldo-regulator-instability-high-frequency-fluctuations (The ESR requirements are the same for these; see fig 12 for 3940).

Comment: @rdtsc, I have 1117-3.3 in any packages but I don't want to use them, I wish more simple solution.

Comment: @beic there is no *more simple* solution than using what you already have on hand...

Comment: The more simple solution than putting in a 3.3V regulator to get 3.3V would be not making anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want is probably something like this (3.3 ohm resistor, 1N4728A Zener):

[image]
[image]

I used two loads 8 and 16 ohms to simulate approximately the current range you want. Beware that as the load current decreases, the power dissipation on the Zener *increases*.

Regulation is pretty "meh" as you can see.

Comment: More people need to specify technical terms in ranges of "meh"

Comment: Given that the question didn't even consider/ask about regulation figures...

Comment: In general, high currents and Zener don't play well together. For comparison, here's a simulation of a setup more similar to something I've used in the past: http://imgur.com/wajTWn2 Lower currents, flatter/better regulation.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff, thank you for the simulation, I will try your solution and report back with results, for the rest of the users I would like to thank you for neg. reps and for down voting my question! (what a childish thing)

Comment: Beware that the way this is set up, if the load current drops under 220mA (including accidentally disconnecting the load), the Zener will release its magic smoke, because 1N4728A can only [safely] dissipate 1W-1.3W (depends on the manufacturer). Also, I can upload LTspice file(s) for you somewhere if you're interested in them.

Comment: @RespawnedFluff but if I replace 1N4728A with 1N5913B, then it would be safe?

Comment: Yes, 1N5913B would be safe up to 6.5V input (with that 3.3 ohm series resistor) then even with no load because it can dissipate 3W. So it should be okay with a 7805 ahead of it.

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to do this you might as well build your own from scratch:

*credits to* [www.google.com](http://www.google.com)
[image: Schematic]

Alternatively, just put a 6Ω 3W resistor in series with the 5V output.  That will keep it around 3.3V for a steady current like you described.  Don't forget you can always parallel cheaper ones.

Comment: He didn't say he wanted a pass transistor.

Comment: No, but he did say he could use extra parts.

Comment: Like one of the many 3.3V LDOs?

Comment: Well that's obviously an option, but he's looking to build something from scratch it looks like.

Comment: I'm all for single package (SMD if possible!) but sometimes you just want to build something you can see.

Comment: @Daniel, Yes, It's good, but...I want 7805 and 2-3 some little extra parts, nothing else.

Comment: Ah, well you could just put a beefy 3.3V zener across the output, but that would be very inefficient.

Comment: @Daniel, like this? [http://i.stack.imgur.com/fFeME.jpg](http://i.stack.imgur.com/fFeME.jpg)

Comment: Like that, except keep in mind the resistor would limit your output current depending on the value.  There are many right ways to do this.

Comment: Yeah, I tough so with that resistor! :(

Comment: IDEA!  You're shorted voltage will be 1.7V, so put a 2 ohm resistor in there with a 3V zener, that should do it right with current limiting only on the zener.  It's worth trying

Comment: How much current do you need out of this, and will it be constant?

Comment: 200-400mA tops, yes, should be constant, I wish to avoid the second voltage regulator for 3.3V

Comment: OK, just put a 6 ohm resistor in series with the output.  That should do the trick

Comment: @Daniel, without zener or?

Comment: No zener, just the resistor to drop the voltage.  If it's a constant current, you can just tweak the R value until it's 3.3V

Comment: @Daniel that simple and 1/4W resistor good for it?

Comment: Watts = Volts * Amps. So 3.3v * 0.4A = 1.32W (real, so de-rate this >50%, so it has to be 2.64W, which is not a standard wattage, so pick the next largest, 3W. It will get HOT.

Comment: Big R, but hey, it's simple!  You can always take 12 1/4W 36Ω resistors and parallel them.