# LTSPICE: How to display traces automatically when press Run Button?

Tags: ltspice

I have a question related to LTSPICE. Some of the examples placed in Educational folder have this feature (i.e. when I press Run button, automatically some traces appear). I analyze example, but I don't find a command, an option or a directive able to make appearing trace automatically. Any idea?

Comment: Are you referring to the .plot command?

Comment: I am wondering this feature too, maybe because it labels the net out1, maybe it is already simulated...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add a trace from a directive in LTSpice](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197042/add-a-trace-from-a-directive-in-ltspice)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After running the simulation, plot the desired waveforms, then activate the waveform viewer (click on its area), and then click on the `Save` button in the toolbar (or in the `File > Save` menu). This creates the `.plt` file. Whenever you first run the simulation, or when you open up the waveform, the saved traces will show up. This answer was also [here](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/197042/add-a-trace-from-a-directive-in-ltspice/375713#375713).